# Is there a way to save an HTML list (UL, LI) to a file, and then retrieve, and display it later?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a "todo list" (mostly "borrowed" from W3) where the user can enter data, and the data is then listed as a "li" object on the site. I want to store the data that the user inputs to a file, so that if the user refreshes, the items on the list will re-appear as they were.

I'm running this locally, so I preferably want to just store it in a textfile with separators.

I have tried to use some JS to get all the items with the tagname "li", but i haven't messed with JS in a long time, and im pretty rubbish. You can see what i tried below.

Javascript:

```
    var arrayList = 
document.getElementById("myUL").getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i=0; i<arrayList.length;i++) {
        alert(arrayList[0].innerHTML);
}
}
```

HTML list:

```
    <h1>Todo</h1>
<div id="myDIV" class="header">
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeydown = "if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('addBtn').click()" placeholder="Task...">
    <span onclick="newElement(), listGet()" id="addBtn" class="addBtn">Add</span>
</div>
<ul id="myUL">

</ul>
</div>
```

This is the alert I get when I enter some text:

```
"Do the dishes<span class="close">×</span>"
```

I would optimally want to only get the text input, then somehow store the information, and display it the next time I refresh the website.

Please let me know if I need to change anything in my question, or if my question is too open. I assume I should only ask questions that have to do with code that is written wrong, not about code that isn't written yet, but I really need someone to point me in the right direction, so its worth a shot.. Thanks!

Comment: You should check out localStorage/sessionStorage objects. This is some kind of storage you can use to store values temporarily for a user in his browser. Also, for the selectors of the input field, I would recommend you using Jquery. Writing files from javascript will not work cross-browser (security/just writing on a client disk without permission seems tricky)

Comment: Thanks, ill read up on it! Im not planning on distributing this, its more of a fun project really.. Might manually give someone the files or something, but i wont be running it live on a server, so i *think* it should be fine... Maybe

Comment: https://codepen.io/webguru071/pen/BgyPmR
You can check this todo list app, It was one of my test projects when I was learning javascript.

Comment: Thanks Shovon! Ill try to implement your solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Using a button click you can store values in Local Storage like:

```
<h1>Todo</h1>
<div id="myDIV" class="header">
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeydown="if(event.keyCode == 13)  placeholder="Task...">
    <button onclick="newElement(), listGet()" id="addBtn" class="addBtn">Add</button>
  </div>
  <ul id="myUL">

  </ul>
</div>


<script  type="text/javascript">
  function newElement(){
     var inputData= document.getElementById("myInput");
     localStorage.setItem("data", inputData.value); // store values using setItem method
  }
</script>


// Get the value from Local Storage

var storedData = localStorage.getItem("data");
```

Answer (score 1):

What are `newElement()` & `listGet()` ?

You can get your `li` nodes by using [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) :

```js
let yourUL = document.getElementById('myUL');
let yourLiNodeList = yourUL.getElementsByTagName('li');
console.log(yourLiNodeList);
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cq653goL/) with a demo :)

Comment: oops, forgot about the saving-in-a-file part but Verthosa already answered with [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) :)